# for-loop crashes python

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, for-loop, ctypes

I have a C library that i wraped in Python with ctypes and I have this DLL below
that prints out the time values when i ask it to. But rather than going through
each item and manually asking it to print out 50000 values for time. I think i created a for loop, but it doesn't work properly.

Here is a small example of my code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

MultiF = (b'path_to_file')   
dll = CDLL('path_to_dll') 

PN = ctypes.c_char_p(b'Paramter_name')
startTime = ctypes.c_double(-value)
stopTime = ctypes.c_double(value)
DT_RETURN = 0x0100
DT_FLOAT = 0x0001
convertType = (DT_RETURN|DT_FLOAT)
Null = 0


dll.readSParm.argtypes = (POINTER(SFile), c_char_p, c_double, c_double, c_double, POINTER(TTag), c_ushort,)   
dll.readSParm.restype = POINTER(SParm)

g = dll.readSParm(f, PN, startTime, stopTime, Null, None, convertType)

print(g[0].time[0])
print(g[0].time[1])
print(g[0].time[50000])
```

these are the return values that the code give me:

```
-1031.0762939453125
-1031.0362548828125
0.0
```

I want to eventually get all of these number into an array to be graphed.
So I created a for loop that is failing:

```
time = (g[0].time)
for i in time:
    print(time[1])
```

This only prints the first value over and over and over again until Python crashes.
My question in this:
How can I get it to run on a loop and print out all 50000 values?

## Edit

This works:

```
 time = (g[0].time)
 for i in time:
    print(i)
```

but then it crashes Python

Comment: `time` is a list of numbers?  If so, `i` in your loop will be the *value*, not the *index*, of each number, so that `time[i]` will not be what you think it is.  But then, if the values are floats, then `time[i]` should cause an error (trying to use a float as an index).

Comment: for i in range(len(time)):

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, `time` is a list of number. I edited the loop I created. `I` doesn't return anything it just throws an error. when I type `time[1]` it prints out the first value over and over again until python crashes. sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @mauve Sorry, but that doesn't work. I get an error that says 'LP_c_float' has no len()

Comment: For the people who keep downvoting this do you mind telling what I did wrong so I can correct it?!

Comment: So you are claiming that `print(g[0].time[1]))` works fine, but `time = (g[0].time); print(time[1])` does not?

Comment: @ScottHunter all three of those work. what didn't work was `for i in time:
    print(time[i])`

Comment: Does this work?  `for i in time: print i`

Comment: @ScottHunter YES!!!! if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `time` is in fact the list of values you want to print, then this should do the trick:

```
for v in time:
    print v
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense based on other questions eliza.b has asked and the comments, in which it's clear that `time` is a ctypes pointer to `c_float` (i.e. `LP_c_float`). You can iterate a ctypes pointer until you reach an unreadable address. Beyond the valid length, the result is nonsense, and should eventually crash Python. I don't know where the magic 50000 value comes from, but you can use it to slice off a list of dereferenced float values, e.g. `time[:50000]`, and iterate that list.

Answer (score 1):

Your're printing out time[1] instead of time[i]. Also, right now i is the value itself for each element in time.

If you want to iterate over all indices of the list and print the value for each one (which is what I assume you want), you need to do

```
for i in range(len(time))
```

which changes your code to

```
time = (g[0].time)
for i in range(len(time)):
    print(time[i])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. When I try your code I get this error  `TypeError: object of type 'LP_c_float' has no len()`

Comment: What about `for i in (time): print i`?